# REST Assured, How to import "from" statically from the JsonPath class?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I'm trying to do something like this, bit is not working fine, I don't get how to import "from" statically from the JsonPath class, that says I should do here:

`// "from" is statically imported from the JsonPath class
List<String> bookTitles = from(response).getList("store.book.findAll { it.price < 10 }.title");`

I'm having this error:

`"cannot find symbol symbol: method from(java.lang.String)"`

Someone would help me please?, thanks in advance :)

Comment: You must add a static import for the from(String) method in the JsonPath class: import static path.to.class.JsonPath.from;

Comment: @IgorRodriguez You should make this into an answer.

Comment: @TheLaw thank you!!! That's I wanted :D

Comment: @IgorRodriguez thank you so much :) a little obvious I didn't realize, thanks :D:D

Answer (score 3):

As @IgorRodriguez says:

> You must add a static import for the from(String) method in the
>   JsonPath class: import static path.to.class.JsonPath.from;

Worked for me :)

In my case it was:

`import static com.jayway.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.from;`